# Obfuscate location to show a given level of accuracy

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, location

Let's say that **I want to get the lastLocation but with an accuracy no better than 1km**, how can I do that? Does Android provide an easy way to do this?

I know that COARSE_LOCATION obfuscate it to a block level, but that isn't enough.

Why I need this? There is a law that requires that in some cases the app shouldnt return an accurate location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's say that I want to get the lastLocation but with an accuracy no better than 1km, how can I do that?

You don't. You get a location. It will have whatever accuracy it has, which you can determine via `getAccuracy()` on the `Location` object. Other than by choosing coarse versus fine, you do not have control over the actual accuracy.

Comment: Then I will need to obfuscate it on my own, any idea how could I do that? How can I add inaccuracy in meters to latitude longitude coordinates?